# Insert query depending on value previously inserted

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm using MySQL in node.js (MySQL module) to manage my database. I have two tables related to one main table as follow:

Table 1 (Main table): `Flights`

```
+-----+-------------+-----------------+
| Id  | CreatedDate |      Notes      |
+-----+-------------+-----------------+
| 1   | 2015-01-01  | No reservations |
| 2   | 2015-02-15  | Without places  |
| ... | ...         | ...             |
+-----+-------------+-----------------+
```

Table 2: `FlightPassengers`

```
+----------+------------+--------+
| IdFlight | Passenger  | Arrive |
+----------+------------+--------+
| 1        | 125        | true   |
| 2        | 115        | false  |
| ...      | ...        | ...    |
+----------+------------+--------+
```

Table 3: `PassangerParameters`

```
+----------+-------------+-------+
| IdFlight |  Parameter  | Value |
+----------+-------------+-------+
| 1        | Age         | 12    |
| 2        | Civil status| S     |
| 2        | Age         | 25    |
| 4        | Civil status| M     |
| 4        | Age         | 40    |
| ...      | ...         | ...   |
+----------+-------------+-------+
```

Right now, when I want to add a flight, I have to make the `INSERT INTO Flights SET ?` MySQL query first and then get the `Flight Id` to make this others querys:

```
INSERT INTO FlightPassengers VALUES (?,?,?)
INSERT INTO PassangerParameters VALUES (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?)
```

to insert the values in the other tables. On this way I feel is very inefficient and uncomfortable, specially for the `PassangerParameters` table.

How can I make this query more efficient? There's a method that I can take to make this properly?

Comment: How are you accessing the database? Most APIs will return the last insert ID when executing an insert query.

Comment: @jwueller I'm using mysql module [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql) . I already get the last insert Id to update my other tables but I want to know if there's an efficient method to do this instead using last insert Id

Comment: Executing those queries one after the other is actually the standard way of doing it. You could use PL/SQL to do it all inside the database engine, but you would still need to execute the queries sequentially. Also, storing logic in the database is usually not a great idea, so I would definitely recommend to just do it in node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [TRIGGER](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/create-the-first-trigger-in-mysql.aspx) to automatically insert into other tables when you insert into `Flights`

```
CREATE TRIGGER insertPassInfo
    AFTER INSERT ON Flights
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO FlightPassengers VALUES (NEW.Id, ?, ?);
        INSERT INTO PassengerParameters VALUES (NEW.Id, ?, ?), (NEW.Id, ?, ?);
    END
```

Comment: That's a good idea, but how do i handle the fact that `PassengerParameters `'s rows could vary in diferents requests? i.e. sometime I have 5, 3 or 1 parameter to set of a passanger